Azure DevOps Pipeline Creation Error: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Path"
I'm trying to create a YAML-based pipeline in Azure DevOps using the Python SDK (azure-devops), but I'm encountering the following error:

azure.devops.exceptions.AzureDevOpsServiceError: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: Path

Code:
Here is the function I’m using to create the pipeline:
from azure.devops.v7_1.pipelines.models import CreatePipelineParameters, CreatePipelineConfigurationParameters



self.pipeline_name = pipeline_name



    pipeline_config_parameters = CreatePipelineConfigurationParameters(type="yaml")



    pipeline_parameters = CreatePipelineParameters(

        configuration=pipeline_config_parameters,

        name=self.pipeline_name

    )



    pipeline_response = self.pipeline_client.create_pipeline(pipeline_parameters, project=project_name)



    print(pipeline_response)

Error:
The error is raised during the create_pipeline method:

azure.devops.exceptions.AzureDevOpsServiceError: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: Path

Question:
How do I correctly specify the YAML file path and repository when creating a pipeline using the Azure DevOps Python SDK?
I’ve tried specifying a YAML path in CreatePipelineConfigurationParameters, but the path parameter doesn’t seem to exist in the SDK version I’m using.
I checked the SDK documentation and could not find a way to provide the YAML file path and repository in the pipeline configuration.

it looks like there is a bug in SDK https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/issues/481

I can reproduce the same error with your python script, as mentioned in the comment, it appears the 'Path' is missed in the configuration.
You can use below script to create the yaml pipeline with yaml files in the devops repo(replace variables to yours):
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
import requests
import json
import base64

# Define variables
organization_url = "https://dev.azure.com/your-organization"
project = "your-project"
repository_id = "your-repository-id"
pipeline_name = "TestYAMLPipeline"
yaml_file_path = "yamlfolder/azure-pipelines.yml"
personal_access_token = "your-personal-access-token"


# Create a connection to the Azure DevOps organization
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

# Get the core client
core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()

# Define the pipeline configuration
pipeline_config = {
    "name": pipeline_name,
    "configuration": {
        "type": "yaml",
        "path": yaml_file_path,
        "repository": {
            "id": repository_id,
            "type": "azureReposGit"
        }
    }
}

# Convert the pipeline configuration to JSON
json_payload = json.dumps(pipeline_config)

# Define the REST API URL
api_url = f"{organization_url}/{project}/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview.1"

# Make the REST API request to create the pipeline
response = requests.post(
    api_url,
    headers={
        "Authorization": f"Basic {base64.b64encode(f':{personal_access_token}'.encode()).decode()}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data=json_payload
)

# Output the response
print(response.json())


Yaml pipeline created successfully:


